# Rename files using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, windows-7-x64

I have a set of files that are all in the same format `somethingname___someotherstuff.txt`

I want to get ride of the `___someotherstuff` bit.

(`___` = 3 underscores)

It is a combination of letter and numbers

How do i do it?

**EDIT:** OS = Windows 7

**EDIT AGAIN:** the 'someotherstuff' bit is not the same in every file.  A combination of different numbers and characters

**EDIT ONCE AGAIN**: somebody answered it and then withdrew it. Why? you had the right answer.
*_* \w+
thanks. put it back if you like and I'll mark yours as the answer

Comment: Unsure, therefore as comment: `ren *___someotherstuff.txt *.txt`. Try this pattern first in a secure location!

Comment: @userunknown - thanks but the 'someotherstuff' bit is different in every file. Sorry if not made clear

Comment: @kurasa - this has very little to do with regexes.  Please retag your question to show your programming language (and OS while you are at it).  (If this is not programming, it would be on a wrong site.)

Comment: @kurasa: It doesn't matter - it wouldn't have worked anyway. Now I remember, that on MS, with copy/del/mv/rename you can only match in the end of a filename part, stemming from 8.3-times independently for every part before and behind the dot (assuming there is just one dot). I don't know for nowadays. Maybe the perl rename is available for windows too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it roughly like this:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
foreach (string f in files)
{
    if (file.IndexOf("___") != -1)
    {
        File.Move(file, Regex.Replace(file, "___.*\.txt$", ""));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex pattern might satisfy the requirement...

```
string newFileName = Regex.Replace(fileName, @"___\w*(?=\.)", "")
```